# how to start a for loop from a chosen row of pandas.df?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, utf-8, gbk

when processing a pandas.df with for loop.I usually meet up with errors. When the error has been removed, I will have to restart the for loop form the beginning of the dataframe. How can I start the for loop from the error position, getting rid of run it repeatedly.
For example:

```
senti = []
for i in dfs['ssentence']:
   senti.append(get_baidu_senti(i))
```

in the code above, I'm trying to do the sentiment analysis through api and store them into a list.However, the api only input GBK format whereas my data are encoded in utf-8. So it usually meet up with errors like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u30fb' in position 14: illegal multibyte sequence
```

So I have to delete the specific items like'\u30fb' manually and restart the for loop.  At this time, the list"senti" contains so many data already so I don't want to abandon them. What can I do to improve the for loop?

Comment: Why not just specify an error handler when encoding?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I have to post data in GBK format, how to write the error handler when encoding?The only thing I can imagine is to delete the error character.

Comment: That's what the error handler can do for you: `.encode('gbk', 'ignore')` skips codepoints that can't be encoded.

Comment: And are you certain that your data is encoded as UTF8? You appear to have string values, so Unicode values already decoded from bytes (UTF-8 implies that you have binary, encoded data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you API requires encoding to GBK, then just encode to that codec using an error handler other than `'strict'` (the default).

`'ignore'` will drop any codepoints that can't be encoded to GBK:

```
dfs['ssentence_encoded'] = dfs['ssentence'].str.encode('gbk', 'ignore')
```

See the [*Error Handlers* section of Python's `codecs` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers).

If you need to pass in strings, but only strings that can safely be encoded to GBK, then I'd create a translation map suitable for the [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
class InvalidForEncodingMap(dict):
    def __init__(self, encoding):
        self._encoding = encoding
        self._negative = set()
    def __missing__(self, codepoint):
        if codepoint in self._negative:
            raise LookupError(codepoint)
        if chr(codepoint).encode(self._encoding, 'ignore'):
            # can be mapped, record as a negative and raise
            self._negative.add(codepoint)
            raise LookupError(codepoint)
        # map to None to remove
        self[codepoint] = None
        return None

only_gbk = InvalidForEncodingMap('gbk')
dfs['ssentence_gbk_safe'] = dfs['sentence'].str.translate(only_gbk)
```

The `InvalidForEncodingMap` class lazily creates entries as codepoints are looked up, so only codepoints that are actually present in your data are processed. I'd still keep the map instance around for re-use if you need to use it more than once, the cache it builds up can be reused that way.